# Angular testing: Testing a method with a type specific argument

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm new to testing and I got into the following situation. My component has a method `closeBox()` that takes an argument of type `Conversation`. `Conversation` is a pretty complex model (see below). If I try to test this method by calling it with a simple object {id:1, name: 'me'}, it requests that it has to be an argument of type `Conversation`.

Now, I was wondering: Do I really have to fake an entire conversation object every time I want to test a method with a type-specific parameter? This conversation model is already a pain in the ass and it's not even that big. Surely there's a better way to do this. Anyone?

**This is the test I am trying to perform: I make sure the fake conversation is present in the array property `openConversations` and then I call the closeBox method with a conversation as argument. as you can see it's a lot of work to create this fake conversation. Is there a better way to do this?**

```
    it('should close the chatbox', function () {
    const mockConversation = new Conversation(
      [{id: 'jos'}],
      {username: 'jos', profilePicture: {name: 'jos', uploaded: true, userId: '12345'}},
      '123456',
      '123457',
      '9875412');
    component.openConversations = [mockConversation];

    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.closeBox(mockConversation);

    expect(component.openConversations).toBe(null);

  });
```

**Component method: this.openConversations is a property of this component. It's an array of Conversations**

```
closeBox(openConv: Conversation) {
    const index = this.openConversations.indexOf(openConv);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.openConversations.splice(index, 1);

    }
  }
```

**Conversation model**

export class Conversation {

```
  constructor(
    public messages: Array<{}>,
    public otherUser: {
      username: string,
      profilePicture: {
        name: string,
        uploaded: boolean,
        userId: string
      }},
    public user1: string,
    public user2: string,
    public _id: string
  ) {}

}
```

Comment: One quick (and potentially hacky) thing you can try is removing the type assigned to `component` at the top of the spec file. This should make the TS compiler unaware of the methods in the component and you should be able to pass them anything. It has the added benefit of allowing you to access, and thus test private methods.

Comment: Thanks Mansour. I'll try it out.